# as3 unload a class when clicking on loaded content

Tags: actionscript-3, class, package, classloader

I loaded a test swf into a class. The swf has its own code that loads a link when clicked. This works fine but I want to UNLOAD the class when the swf is clicked.

How can I unload a class when clicking on the loaded content?

I called the function "meow", a simply random name, as I am testing anyway. :)

Here is what I have that does not work:

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; 


    public class theAd extends MovieClip
    {


        public function theAd()
        {


            var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
            my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.massmediamail.com/testing/Manga.swf"));

 my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startListener);



            function startListener(e:Event):void
            {
                addChild(my_loader.content);
                trace("Content Loaded");
                my_loader.content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, meow);


            }

            function meow(e:Event):void
            {
                //this.parent.parent.removeChild(this);
                trace(this.name);

            }


        }




    }

}
```

Comment: what is `this.parent.parent`? is it a `Loader`? do you get any errors?

Comment: `this.parent.parent.removeChild(this)` will not work because `this` is  not the child of its parents parent. try `this.parent.removeChild(this)` or `this.parent.parent.removeChild(this.parent)` but both of these codes are pretty ugly and you should deal with removal in the parent class tbh

Comment: Still didn't work. I ended up using a call to a function on in the Main.as class. It was quite a work around but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having troubles with correct removal of `loader.content`? You should employ `event.target` property to get the correct instance.

```
function meow(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var mc:DisplayObject=e.target;
    if (!mc) return;
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want to unload the class called theAd.as that loads the content.  I ended up using a call to a function on in the Main.as class. It was quite a work around but it works. However, it was unrelated to the question I asked.

Comment: You don't need to unload just an empty transitional MC, IMHO. But if you want, you add `e.target` to stage, then go `this.parent.removeChild(this)` and that's all.